# Select multiple table in mysql with text instead of id

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, union, multiple-columns

I have 3 tables - `article`, `stof`, `elementen`.
In the article table are the all articles linked with the `stofid` and `elementid` to the `stof` and `elementen` table.

Now the problem is I need to do a search in the article table (using AJAX) but I can't search with the `elementid` and `stofid` because they are id's instead of text.

The script:

```
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

require('../config/db/db.inc.php');
$q = anti($_GET["q"]);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE omschrijving LIKE '%".$q."%' AND visibile='1' OR id LIKE '".$q."%' AND visibile='1' OR aanvullend LIKE '".$q."%' AND visibile='1' OR inkoopomschrijving LIKE '%".$q."%' AND visibile='1' OR verkoopomschrijving LIKE '%".$q."%' AND visibile='1' ORDER BY inkoopomschrijving ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $result_element = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elementen WHERE id='".$row['elementid']."' ");
        while($row_element = mysql_fetch_array($result_element)){
            $element = $row_element['element'];
        }
        $result_stof = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stof WHERE id='".$row['stofid']."' ");
        while($row_stof = mysql_fetch_array($result_stof)){
            $stof = $row_stof['stof'];
        }
        echo "<p style=\"margin:0.0em auto;\"><a href=\"./artikel.php?artikel_id=".$row['id']."\" title=\"". $row['omschrijving'] . ' ' . $element . ' ' . $stof . "\" style=\"color:black;\">" . $row['omschrijving'] . ' ' . $element . ' ' . $stof . '</a></p>';

}
```

You see that I am using 2 new mysql query to get the text instead of ids, but I want also make it available to search full text.

Comment: I'm not understanding. why can't you search for an id? id's are generally just numbers. numbers are quite literally much EASIER to search for than strings.

Comment: its for a program and the users search for article name, but we got so many article. If you only search on "Woonkamer Okso" you get like 200 articles, so they need the possibilty to search article+element+1 more field, but the last 2 fields are ids instead of tekst. so the query needs to get the tekst from another table with the ids in the article table.